# Is the notion of "expression" formal/rigorous enough?

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, notation

For any set $S$ and field $k$, one can form the vector space over $k$ with basis $S$. As a set, this is the set of all linear combinations ("expressions") of the form $\sum_i\alpha_is_i$ where $\alpha_i\in k$, $s_i\in S$, and all but finitely many $\alpha_i$ are zero. I thought this was a perfectly rigorous definition until I read [Example 1.2.4(c)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf) which, in particular, says:

> To be completely precise and avoid talking about "expressions", we can define $F(S)$ [the vector space in question] to be the set of all functions $\lambda: S\to k$ such that $s\in S:\lambda(s)\ne 0\}$ is finite.

Why would one want to "rigorize" further the notion of expression and avoid talking about it? Isn't it a perfectly well- and rigorously defined notion already?

Comment: If "expression" were formal, what would be its definition? Would "$u \div$" be one? Or if $u$ and $v$ were known elements of an arbitrary vector space, would "$u^v$" be one? I have no doubt that an "expression" can be formalised on a context-by-context basis (which is what's happening here), but I doubt there's a sensible, useful definition for mathematics in general.

Comment: @TheoBendit Isn't the notion of linear combiation formal? Namely, it is a sum of the form $\sum \alpha_i s_i$. And an expression is defined to be a linear combination. As for the 2nd and 3rd sentences in your comment, I don't know what that notation stands for.

Comment: @user634426: Theo's point is that "$u\div$" or "$u^v$" **are not** among the "expressions" you want to deal with, and in order to have a rigorous definition you need to have an actual definition about which strings of symbols you're talking about _and which strings of symbols you are not_.

Comment: @HenningMakholm But the definition of a linear combination contains the information about which strings of symbols are "allowed" and which are not, as far as I understand. And if an expression is defined as a linear combination, then those two "things" from Theo's comment are not expressions.

Comment: @user634426: Does it? There may be such a description in the book you're working from, but you have certainly not quoted any such description in your quotestion.

Comment: @user634426 Linear combinations are another context-sensitive definition of expression. They're well-defined enough for the given context, but someone had to specifically define them for certain operations and variables (again, a bit like the quote from the textbook). They're not a definition for the general term "expression".

Comment: @HenningMakholm I assumed there is a "universal"/standard definition of a $k$-linear combination of elements of any set $S$ (from any book in linear algebra).

Comment: @user634426: Yes, there is a standard definition of linear combination. It's the one you have quoted following the words "To be completely precise". You seem to be dissatisfied with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example, if your $S$ consists of the letters $a$, $b$, and $c$, are the strings "$1a$" and "$1a+0b$" and "$0c+1a$" all expressions? If they are all expressions, then are they all elements of your vector space? Are they *different* elements? If you say they are all elements of your vector space, but are *the same* element, then how to you get that from any concept of "expression"? They are certainly not the same strings of symbols.

If "$1a+0b$" is *not* an expression, then which expression is the zero element of your vector space?

How about "$1a+1a$" versus "$2a$"?

How about "$1a+2b$" versus "$2b+1a$"? There is nothing in your informal description that says $S$ comes with a preferred ordering, but *expressions* are always finite strings of symbols that appear in a particular order.

---

These problems are not insurmountable showstoppers. It is absolutely *possible* to give a rigorous definition of "expression", and then define your vector space as the quotient of a set of expressions by all identities that are provable in a certain formal theory -- but doing all that turns out to be *more work* and in the end less convenient and less rewarding than speaking about functions $S\to k$ with finite support.

---

A more rewarding thing to do with expressions would be to start by looking at the set of *all* expressions that can be built with the vector space operations, such as $3\cdot(5\cdot((-b)+7\cdot a+13\cdot(\vec0+c)))$. That is, *don't* a priori restrict to expressions of a particular form. The quotient out all identities that can be proved from the axioms for $k$-vector spaces (and arithmetic on $k$).

This *still* gives you a vector space of formal linear combinations of $S$, but this time around the entire construction is openly an example of a general concept of *free models* for equational theories. This is arguably worthwhile because it shows conceptual parallels to things that might not immediately look similar.

On the other hand, one of the first things one would *do* with this construction is probably to prove that it is isomorphic to the space of finitely supported functions $S\to k$, and then use the latter for actual computations.

Comment: Right, if I define an expression as a sum $\sum \alpha_i s_i $, then nothing tells me that $1a$ and $1a+0b$ are the same element. But why should they be the same element? Does it follow from vector space axioms or only from common sence? And if I define an expression as a function (as quoted), then $1a$ corresponds to (according to the remark in the cited text) $\lambda(a)a$ and $1a+0b$ corresponds to $\lambda(a)a+\lambda(b)b$. Why are these expressions (according to this formal definition) the same expression?

Comment: @user634426: With the common definition (which you quoted), there is one element of the vector space represented by the function $\{a\mapsto 1,b\mapsto 0,c\mapsto 0\}$. This single element is what we mean when we write the informal expressions $1a$ or $1a+0b$, or even $a$.

Comment: @user634426: It is possible that you can find a useful vector space structure on a set that contains the strings $1a$ and $1a+0b$ as different elements. It just won't be what people generally mean when they speak of the space of formal linear combinations. And the point of having a definition is to make such things explicit!

Comment: Apparently I didn't know until today about the formal definition of linear combination. Even relatively serious text like Artin or Axler only define linear combinations as sums of the form $\sum \alpha_i s_i$, but not as functions.

Comment: So if we use the rigorous definition, we also don't need to worry about what exactly the multiplication $\alpha_i s_i$ is, right? (That's the problem littleO pointed out in his answer.)

Comment: @user634426: The Artin I have a copy of ("Algebra", Prentice-Hall 1991) mostly only defines formal linear combinations (at the end of section 3.3) when $S$ is explicitly assumed to be a _"finite ordered set whose elements are distinct"_. In that case it makes sense to specify that an expression must contain all of the $s$ in the given order, which eliminates the ambiguities here. There's a single sentence that alludes to formal linear combinations of an _infinite_ set; that sentence does seem to sweep all of the subtleties under the carpet.

Comment: @user634426: Correct, you don't need to worry about $\alpha_i s_i \cdot \alpha_j s_j$. Even in the intuitive view where you ignore the subtleties, such an expression would never arise out of use of the allowed vector space operations.

Comment: I meant the multiplication of an element of $k$ by an element of $S$, not the product $\alpha_is_i\cdot \alpha_j s_j$.

Comment: @user634426: Ah. In both cases you would need an actual definition of how scalar multiplication works in your new vector space. This definition can be short and simple when your vectors are functions $S\to k$ with finite support, but it does need to be there. In the simple "expression" view you can sort of get away with claiming the right definition follows from the distributive law. But then there's really a lot of heavy lifting being done by a notion of "expression" that doesn't yet have a rigorous definition.

Comment: Yes, I would defenitely need a definition of scalar multiplication and addition in the vector space (and it's given in the book cited), but what I meant is that I don't have to worry about what kind of product is used in the "expression" $\alpha s$ because such "expression" is formally just a function, and the question pointed out in littleO's answer doesn't even arise, as far as I understand. (Unlike in the case of the informal definition.)

Comment: @user634426: Yes, that is right.

Answer (score 1):

$S$ is just a set with no structure, so it is not clear what is meant by multiplying an element of $S$ by a scalar, or adding together two elements of $S$. If $S$ were assumed to be a vector space over a field $F$ this would be no problem. But $S$ is just a set, so we must carefully define what we mean by taking linear combinations of elements of $S$.

For example, suppose that $S$ is, say, the set of all lines in a given plane. Without further explanation, it's not clear what it would mean to take a linear combination of elements of $S$.

Comment: "If $S$ were assumed to be a vector space over a field $F$ this would be no problem." Ironically, if one is not careful about distinguishing distinct operations, pre-existing additive structures could pose a big problem when trying to form a free additive structure.

Comment: @TheoBendit An example is the group ring $\Bbb Z[G]$, which is formally the set of maps $G\to \Bbb Z$ that are $\ne0$ only for finitely many $x\in G$, or les formally linear combinations of elements of $G$ with coefficients in $\Bbb Z$. The poblems you mention occur for example when we consider $\Bbb Z[\Bbb Z]$ and the various meanings of $+$ and $\cdot$ therin